PC as a rebuttal to the Gettier case against JTB definition of knowledge
Recently I had an exchange with someone that involved my asking her how she defined knowledge. To which she responded, “Justified true belief.”
Knowing of the numerous Gettier cases I explained to her my reason for rejecting that definition. She explained how she’s aware of the Gettier cases (she had a simple understanding of EG’s first Clock Analogy.) And proceeded to give what I thought was a really odd rebuttal to the Gettier case.
She explained that under a phenomenological view, more specifically phenomenal conservatism; one may believe something to be true until they’ve been given a sufficient reason to believe otherwise.
I explained that I understand Gettier’s case to be a defeater of JTB. If something is objectively true and your belief leads you to think it’s false (despite the fact that you may feel justified) at least within a more traditional epistemic framework — it’s not considered knowledge.
What is the most current epistemically sound take on this rebuttal? Is it valid? Is there something I’m missing?

I define knowledge as true belief. The justification condition and others added in response to Gettier's arguments always struck me as poorly motivated. If you want to argue over the justification of beliefs, knock yourself out, but don't tangle those issues up with the definition of a commonly used and useful word.

Knowledge is justified true belief for which the justification also does not make any false assumptions. This includes that the justification should not involve any inferences that rely on an implicit picture of things that isn't the case.

A person may choose to believe something until they have a sufficient reason to believe otherwise, but that would hardly qualify as knowledge in the ordinary sense of the term. All kinds of absurd and even contradictory things would be knowledge under that definition. Gettier cases are still considered by epistemologists to refute JTB, though there are some dissenters.

@Bumble This was sort of my response while talking to her as well. What are some absurd things that might qualify as knowledge under this view?

Take your pick. There are purple unicorns living on a planet somewhere in the galaxy. There are no purple unicorns living on a planet in the galaxy. Or maybe just something mundane. Fermat really did prove the theorem named after him. Pythagoras ate porridge every day. Genghis Khan didn't know how to swim. Some T.Rex's had bright red skin. I don't have a sufficient reason to disbelieve any of these, but it doesn't follow that I know them to be true.

@DavidGudeman True beliefs are called lightweight knowledge by some, but even they admit that this is not how "know" is commonly used. People typically do not say that A knows X, true or not, when A happens to believe X by accident. Justification condition was not added in response to Gettier, it was there since Plato to better match the common use. JTB+ conditions may have their flaws, but your 'definition' is simply not of the commonly used word, hence not very useful. There is no simple fix that would be.

@Conifold, I didn't mean that Gettier inspired the justification condition. As to the rest, I disagree. I don't think most people would think that justification is a part of what they mean when they say that someone knows something. The examples of unjustified true belief are all rather contrived and are not the sort of thing that enters into common language.

Xander -- no justification can ever logically close -- see Munchausen Trilemma.  We also have no access to "truth".  Yet we have knowledge.  So neither logically closing justification, nor truth access can be necessary criteria for knowledge.  Your discussant, in arguing for phenomenal conservatism, should have said she holds views by partial justification -- the preponderance of support -- and left knowledge out of her definition entirely.

@Bumble -- none of your postulated views (T-rex skin color, porridge for breakfast, etc.) has any justification whatsoever.  They are not justified under phenomenal conservatism, so citing them as noteworthy for not having counter evidence either is not a refutation of phenomenal conservatism.

@Xander -- following on my comment to you above, that partial justification can lead to beliefs that then later fail check cases -- is just how life is.  Gettier cases, where a very unlikely bizarre logic event applies, are a minor subset of the problem of complete justification being impossible.  Empiricists have loads of real cases to point to, through history, of knowledge being later overturned, without having to cite Gettier.  But unless you accept incomplete justification that can be later overturned, then you are left with us having no knowledge whatsoever.

@Dcleve My examples were intended to operate against the more general claim that a person may know something just because of lack of evidence to the contrary. As to phenomenal conservatism in particular, I don't find it plausible. I agree that there is some knowledge; that knowledge does not require absolute proof; and that knowledge is sometimes overturned. None of those requires acceptance of phenomenal conservatism. Gettier cases simply show that JTB does not work as an account of knowledge.

One of the primary occupations of philosophy is to sort out the difference between actuality and appearances (springer.com). (Or to cast doubt that actuality exists at all for those who challenge metaphysical realism (SEP).) Thus, from an epistemological perspective, we can see that Gettier's strategy like those who did so before him for undermining Plato in Meno and Theaetetus is to show that one can appear to have sufficient justification of knowledge, but in actuality one does not.
Phenomenal conservatism therefore attempts to take advantage about this gap between appearance and actuality by calling to the fore the rather obvious fact that most people believe they know precisely because there are limits to our access to actuality. Just like modern AI researchers long ago recognized that human rationality is necessarily bounded (SEP), so too do phenomenal conservatives recognize that at some point, we must simply declare, this appears to be actual enough! Consider the contrivance that goes into Gettier problems.
In the first example, Smith does not have unlimited access to evidence. He has enough evidence to reasonable warrant his conclusion, and in the absence of awareness of defeaters Smith reasonably believes his justification to be adequate about his competitor and the coins. Thus, while the actual situation for both conjuncts is unknown to Smith, Smith is unaware of either defeater. And being unaware of the defeater, Smith believes his justification to be sufficient.
In the second example, Smith again has reasonably reached two conclusions about the disjuncts, but does not have unlimited access to what is actually true. Smith is again unaware that his reasonable justification has been compromised. And yet, intuitively, the justification which appears sufficient is actually deficient given the full scope of actual facts.
So, according to modern fallibilism (IEP) which dominates professional epistemological, we must accept that no amount of justification ever gets us to knowledge certainly, and yet accept that knowledge is possible at the risk of falling into radical skepticism, which is equally distasteful. From the IEP:

Fallibilism is the epistemological thesis that no belief (theory, view, thesis, and so on) can ever be rationally supported or justified in a conclusive way. Always, there remains a possible doubt as to the truth of the belief.

Thus, a phenomenal conservative might accept this situation and simply cleave to the importance of recognizing that most situations, unlike the contrived Gettier cases, are actually as they appear. The man next to me on the bus is going to work with his construction outfit, and not a spy. The hamburger provides me nutrition and is not poisoned. My wife is late from work because of a cranky customer who refuses to leave and is not having an affair. If one were to try to rule out all conceivable Gettier-like problems, one might be diagnosed with paranoia! Hence the important heuristic of PC:

If it seems to S that p, then, in the absence of defeaters, S thereby has at least some degree of justification for believing that p.

Thus, one might find a way of reconciling the idea that knowledge is fallible, and but that knowledge, given our limits of justification, is still possible. Phenomenal conservatism allows that by allowing the justification to occur in degrees. Thus, we move from mere belief, to somewhat justified, to strongly justified, while recognizing there is no absolute certainty of any knowledge. Reason and empirical experience is unavoidably defeasible (SEP), after all.

Thus, PC is an assault on an unrealistic demand that we must have a God-like omniscience of reality to be sure, and is equally effective at undermining that requirement as pragmatic encroachment.

Yes.  We have knowledge, even though our justifications do not close, and we do not have access to "truth".  JTB is unachievable, for either of its first two terms, yet we humans have developed a massively useful collection of knowledge about our world.

@Dcleve The one-true-reality mentality is a degenerate form of solipsism, no? It seems to afford no room for being of another mind :D

JD -- I am a realist, and operate on the presumption that there IS a reality.  But that we cannot know what that reality is, only infer it.  Truth would therefore be unavailable for us to use as a knowledge criteria.

@Dcleve That's interesting. So, it's not that justification is relative, but rather that truth is unavailable. I'll have to reflect on that, thanks! :D

JD -- Justification is also forever incomplete.  We can never fully justify anything, so our knowledge can later be shown to have been in error, when we get more data.    Both J and T are unachievable in JTB.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JD Thank you for your answer, I’m at work and I’ve just read over it. I’ll have to take a more in-depth look at it a little later.
It seems though, that JTB as epistemologists have traditionally viewed justification is confused. In other words, you may think you’re justified in believing something that happens to align itself with objective reality. But also it may not. And so your own subjective justification — doesn’t necessarily graft onto what is objectively true outside of your own experience.

I'd say that's a good summary. Historically, epistemology has focused on empirical evidence and rational coherence, but in more recent times, moving away from propositional attitudes and logic, justification is more of a doxastic enterprise, instead relying on psychological reliability and priority. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reliabilism/, and don't hesitate to interrogate me.
